# Cypress: Page doesn't load within the second 'it' block for the click action

Tags: javascript, automation, mocha.js, cypress

It works fine for the same click event if I've coded within the single 'it' block as below.

**Working code:**

```
describe('Test Suite', () => {
    it('Test case 1', () => {
        //Test 1
        //Test 2
    })
})
```

**Not working:**

```
describe('Test Suite', () => {
    it('Test case 1', () => {
        //Test 1
    })
    it('Test case 2', () => {
        //Test 2
    })
})
```

Below is my code snippet, First 'it' block works fine after login method executes. Then second it blocks just clicking the right element but the page never loads.

**P.S.** If I written the code under the single 'it' block, Page loads and works fine.

```
describe('Fund Manager Suite', () => {

    //Checking Fund Manager page loading 
   before(() => {

    cy.visit('xxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    cy.login('xxxxx', 'xxxxx')

   })
   
   it('fund manager navigation works', () => {
    cy.location('pathname').should('equal', '/xxxxx')
    cy.get('#appSwitcher').click()

    cy.get('#appSwitcher > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > :nth-child(2) > a').click()
    cy.location('pathname').should('equal', '/xxxxx')
    cy.get('.k-grid-table').find('tr').should('have.length', 5)
   })

   it('fund detail works', () => {
    cy.get('.product > :nth-child(2)').click()
    cy.location('pathname').should('equal', '/xxxxx')

    // Fund Detail - Search
    cy.get('#s2id_autogen31').type('Rach')
    cy.get('#select2-result-label-32').click()
    cy.get('#searchSubmit').click()
    cy.get('#DataTables_Table_0').find('tr').should('have.length', 10)
       
   })

})
```

[Execution Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXlSv.jpg)
[Code snippet screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCzmv.jpg)

Comment: Do you have `before()` or `beforeEach()` block.

Comment: @AlapanDas I'm having before(() => {. As I want to stay logged in and no need to rerun the login scenario in my second test.

Comment: @AlapanDas Tried with  Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('session_id', 'remember_token') still it does not load the page. If I coded the same with 1 'it' block it works fine.

Comment: Pls add some of the code for the test next time - your question is like a blank form. If it contains some personal data - do the effort to edit the data, so people can help you

Comment: @RosenMihaylov I have updated my code snippet above. Kindly check it out.

Comment: @AlapanDas Please find the update code snippet and image attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Able to resolve this issue by storing the session_id.

```
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
  preserve: "session_id"
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to preserve your cookies in `beforeEach()` to make sure that you stay logged in, in all `it()` blocks. You can read more in [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies.html#Preserve-Once).

```
describe('Dashboard', () => {
  before(() => {
    // log in only once before any of the tests run.
    // your app will likely set some sort of session cookie.
    // you'll need to know the name of the cookie(s), which you can find
    // in your Resources -> Cookies panel in the Chrome Dev Tools.
    cy.login()
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    // before each test, we can automatically preserve the
    // 'session_id' and 'remember_token' cookies. this means they
    // will not be cleared before the NEXT test starts.
    //
    // the name of your cookies will likely be different
    // this is an example
    Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('session_id', 'remember_token')
  })

  it('displays stats', () => {
    // ...
  })

  it('can do something', () => {
    // ...
  })

  it('opens a modal', () => {
    // ...
  })
})
```

Comment: Tried with the above steps. Still the same error.Timed out after waiting 60000ms for your remote page to load.

Your page did not fire its load event within 60000ms.

Comment: Did you replace the `session_id` and `token` with actual values ? You can refer to this article for more info on how to get cookies for your application - https://thereluctanttester.com/2018/02/24/creating-and-preserving-cookies-with-cypress-io/

Comment: I'm trying to pass the token into that. But token changes dynamically after certain period of time. Will handle that and let you know. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I Have seen this kind of behavior, when the first `it case`  start and doesn`t finish some xhr request in the site - and in result cypress continues the process during the start of the second it case. The best solution for clean slate for each case I had found is to separate every case in different file

Comment: This is absolutely correct, but I can't fix it even when I wait (with cy.intercept). It crashes either way, every time. 
I can only have one `it` case per file, which seems crazy to me. How did you solve this?